# How to accept basic auth in a single url route in zend2 or php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, basic-authentication

Say I have a url in zend2 or any php script

```
mysite.com/api/getData
```

In postman say I hot the url directly, mysite.com/api/getData, I will get a code 401.

In postman, I append something like this in the header

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

Then I should be able to see some json data.

```
{msg: 'success'}
```

My understanding is that base64_encode($username:$password) will generate the token like `QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`

My question is that in my zend2 controller, how do I get take the token and verify it?

Comment: $this->params()->fromHeader() doesn't work?

Comment: as @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ said you should be able to retrieve the data directly in the controller. Best practices would be to implement a middleWare that handles authentication and acl.

Comment: If your validation is not only on one controller, i'd suggest you setup a middleWare for this. Bind an event right after the 'dispatch' in the zf2 workflow, then you will be able to handle your checks, and build an identity for the user that you can inject in your request params. There is a tutorial on how to do so here : https://juriansluiman.nl/article/147/api-header-based-authentication-in-zend-framework-2. It's a bit more complicated that what you need but it's well made and you can adapt to your need.